# How to print on physical printer from oracle forms 6i or 11g?

Tags: oracle, plsql

i'm trying to print directly from Oracle form 6i or 11g to a physical printer. The printer appears only in device manager as LPT1, not showing in device and printers. Is there any way to pass the data of a sales ticket to this printer?

Comment: Wow - it's been a while since I had to do this. If memory serves you should be able to access the printer as "LPT1:", but if there's no device driver you may have to generate printer control codes on your own. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi Bob, i know this an old fashion question, but anyhow , it is defined as LPT1, this is not the problem. the question is how to send the codes from oracle form pl/sql to this port?

Comment: Try opening it using UTL_FILE.